# Tags being misformated by Terraforms aws_vpc data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am using Terraforms data provider to get the tags applied to a VPC.

It turns out that if the tag's key has a "." in it like the ones applied automatically by EKS then the tag is returned wrong.

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc_data" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["my-vpc"]
  }

  depends_on = ["null_resource.vpc"]
}
```

For example a tag of;

```
key = "kubernetes.io/cluster/my-cluster"
value = "shared"
```

instead of being returned as;

```
"kubernetes.io/cluster/my-cluster" = "shared"
```

gets returned as;

```
"kubernetes" = map[io/cluster/my-cluster:shared]"
```

Anyone else seen this happening?

Comment: This looks a lot like a parsing error on Terraform's part and something that should be reported as a bug.

Comment: Raised as https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/20554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this issue, it will be fixed in Terraform v 0.12
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10876

A workaround would be to use an external data source to return the tags, something like this Python Gist
https://gist.github.com/alastairhm/f0792d143be31f26d715d8e29055e715

Turns out even using an external data source the resulting map is broken by Terraform parsing of the returned JSON object :(